# Trait as Singleton

Tags: scala, singleton, traits

Is it possible to have a `trait` be a `singleton`?

What I am trying to achieve is to have a clean and lightweight API I can extend throughout my application like the following:

```scala
trait SingletonTrait {
  // element I wish to be unique throughout my application
  val singletonElement = ///

  ...
}

// uses *singletonElement*
object MainApplication extends SingletonTrait {
  ...
}

// uses *singletonElement*
class SomeClass(...) extends SingletonTrait {
  ...
}
```

In the same idea implied by a `getOrCreate()` function that would retrieve an existing instance of an element if one already exists or creates it otherwise.

Comment: What is wrong with a good old-fashioned `object` with a `lazy val`?

Comment: If it is a **Singleton** why do you need to inject it with a `trait`. Why not simply define an `object` and call it directly when you need it? - _(PS: Take into a account, that there are good reasons why the Singleton is an infamous pattern, like difficulty for testing and high cohesion)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez @Tim I feel the ability to `extend` a `trait` is a nice feature.

Comment: @wipman why exactly? I can only see a reason. And it would be making the **Singleton** _"private"_. Thus, only accessible to values that extends the trait. But, even if I do think that is useful. Technically speaking, that wouldn't be a **Singleton**  in the formal sense.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes: a library of features with a shared state accessible only to some components of an application.

Comment: @wipman What happens if someone does
`object Foo extends SingletonTrait {val singletonElement = somethingElse}`? Your singleton assumption falls apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you could do this like so

```
object SingletonElement {
  var count = 0
}

trait SingletonTrait {
  final val singletonElement = SingletonElement
}

object MainApplication extends SingletonTrait {
  singletonElement.count = singletonElement.count + 1
}

class SomeClass extends SingletonTrait {
  singletonElement.count = singletonElement.count + 1
}
```

We can test that the same object is used like so

```
new SomeClass
MainApplication
SingletonElement.count
```

which should output

```
res2: Int = 2
```

which shows the same `SingletonElement` was used.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just create value in *companion object* and reference it in *trait*?

```
trait SingletonTrait {
  final lazy val singletonElement = SingletonTrait.SingletonElement
}

object SingletonTrait {
  lazy val SingletonElement = {
    println("Creating singleton element!")
    "singleton element"
  }
}

// uses *singletonElement*
class SomeClass() extends SingletonTrait {
    println(s"Using ${singletonElement} in class.")
}

new SomeClass()
new SomeClass()
new SomeClass()
```

It prints:

```
Creating singleton element!
Using singleton element in class.
Using singleton element in class.
Using singleton element in class.
```

Comment: No point making it lazy in the companion object and not in the trait :) In fact, I'd make the trait member a `final def` to avoid wasting memory.

Comment: This is a `trait` that self-references? How can this actually function? Could you share some insights, please? I can have any `type` for `SingletonElement`?

Comment: `SingletonTrait` has companion object (which is always singleton), which holds the instance of `SingletonElement`, which is then referenced in *trait*.